# jquery jqwidgets listbox disappearing when submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

I am trying to learn a little about jquery and working with some UI widgets (JQWidgets). I am trying to get call a php script and call back some data in json format. I know that the json format is correct because I can get a listbox to show and run correctly if I just run it straight through. I am trying to type a value into a textbox and when I click on a submit button it will return a list of data into the listbox. When I click the button, the outline of box shows then disappears. I am not sure what I am doing.

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //create jqxButton widget
    $("#btnSubmit").jqxButton({ width: '150'});
    //create jqxListBox widget
    $("#btnSubmit").bind('click', function() {
        //Do som

        var textValue = $("#txtSearch").val();

        var url = "include/showsearch.php?show_name='" + textValue + "'"; //returns json data
        var source =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'name' },
                    { name: 'id' }
                ],
                url:url
            };
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        dataAdapter.dataBind();
        //crate jqxList widget
        $("#search_grid").jqxListBox({source: dataAdapter,selectedIndex: 0,theme:'classic',displayMember: "name", valueMember:"id",itemHeight:70,height:'75%',width:'100%'});
    });
});
```

Partial HTML:

```
  <div id="content1">

      <form id="search">
    <label for="search">Search For:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="q">
          <input style='margin-top: 20px;' type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
<div id="search_grid">
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana;" id="selectionlog">
</div>  
</div>
    <div id="content2">
            <div id="dl_grid">  
</div></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I also want to mention that I am using 000webhost and I turned off the tracking script they use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably your ListBox's height setting. If you want to define height in percentages, your container element should be with "height" defined, too, because 75% of something which is with auto-height by default would be equal to 0. Take a look at: [jQWidgets ListBox with Size in Percentages](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistbox/listbox-fluid-size.htm?arctic)

Comment: I changed them to set sizes, but it didn't work. thanks for the suggestion